# homework assignment function given a string, loop through and console.log() only the vowels. I'm stuck on one thing

Tags: javascript

I have a function takes a string and logs only the vowels of this string. Currently each vowel is logged on a new line and that is no good.

```
function vowelsOnly(str) {
    let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']; 
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(str[i]) > -1 ) {
            // newstr convert to string
            let newstr = str[i].toString();
            console.log(newstr);
        }
        // if no vowels in str log empty string
        else {
            console.log("");
        }
    }
}
```

I need assistance making my code replicate this example: Input is "welcome to my world" expected output is "eoeoo" no commas.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT this code is working for me.

```
const str = "qqwwrrttppssddaeu"
const vowels = str => str.split('').filter(i=>"aeiou".includes(i)).join('');
let newstr = vowels(str).length;
if (newstr > 1){
    console.log(vowels(str));
}
else {
  console.log("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [string iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) to iterate over string.

Obviously the input needs to be processed to generate the result which goes to `console.log`. The effective tool to do it would be [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which iterates the array *implicitly*. The array could be obtained by [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). To put it together, the algorithm can be expressed as

```
const vowels = str => str.split('').filter(i=>"aeiou".includes(i)).join('');
```

So you can get the result by calling

```
console.log(vowels("welcome to my world"))
```

Enjoy functional javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Store all vowels in an array. Then join the array and return it

```js
const str = 'asdrqwfsdgobopwkodvcxvuqbe'

console.log(vowelsOnly(str))

function vowelsOnly(str) {
  const result = []
  let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) {
      result.push(str[i])
    }
  }
  return result.join('')
}
```

one-liner

```js
const str = 'asdrqwfsdgobopwkodvcxvuqbe'

console.log(str.match(/[aeiou]/g).join(''))
```

Comment: Sort of fits my needs....I need to return a blank string if no vowels present in str.

Comment: If the reader is familiar with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  you can shorten this answer to `return Array.from(str).filter(chr => vowels.includes(chr)).join('')`

Comment: @JonBeckner it returns a blank string when no vowels has been found

Comment: using console.log(str.match(/[aeiou]/g).join('')) I tried something similar but couldn't get the blank string if no vowels. is this doable?

Comment: There is no difference between `console.log()` and `console.log('')` how do you test if the string is blank?

Comment: .log() part makes sense. I did it wrong the first time. Answered my own question.